# How to push data from project copy to live-copy using Custom Rollout Configuration?

Tags: aem

I have to make a custom rollout configuration yo send updated data on live copy.Please help me out.

Comment: Care to add a bit of code and what you need help on and fully clarify your question? What's not working? What do you need help with? Is something broken? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom LiveActionFactory by extending  com.day.cq.wcm.msm.api.LiveActionFactory associate it with a custom LiveAction

e.g.

```
@Component(metatype = false)
@Service
public class ExampleLiveActionFactory implements LiveActionFactory<LiveAction> {
    @Property(value="exampleLiveAction")
    static final String actionname = LiveActionFactory.LIVE_ACTION_NAME;

    //stuff
    //more stuff

    public LiveAction createAction(Resource config) {
        return new ExampleLiveAction(name, config);
    }


private static class ExampleLiveAction implements LiveAction {
    public void execute(Resource source, Resource target,
            LiveRelationship liverel, boolean autoSave, boolean isResetRollout) throws WCMException {
        //do your stuff
    }
  }
```

after deploying this in AEM go to Tools/MSM/Rollout Configurations folder and click New > New Page; create a new rollout config. the name for the new rollout config should be same as what you have put in the value property while defining the live action.

You should have a custom rollout config now.